category of pages not showing in front url
I've tested multiple plugins such as "Pages with Category and Tag" on my latest WordPress installation running PHP 8.1. Even with the default theme and only this plugin active, I'm unable to get category pages to display correctly on the frontend. When I try accessing a page using a URL like https://www.example.com/categoryname/page.html, it results in a "Page Not Found" error.
However, the admin interface displays everything correctly, and I've also experimented with permalink settings like / %category% / %postname% /.
Could someone please assist me in configuring WordPress to correctly display pages with assigned category tags in the frontend URLs?
